# if condition is not working in django post request

Tags: python, django

I'm check null values from the request but creating record on null after put the condition in views you can check my code.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    category_id = request.POST['category_id ']
    text1       = request.POST['text1']
    text2       = request.POST['text2']
    text3       = request.POST['text3']

    product = Product(category_id=category_id, text=text1) 
    product.save()

    if text2 is not None:
        product = Product(category_id=category_id, text=text2) 
        product.save()
        
    if text3 is not None:
        product = Product(category_id=category_id, text=text3) 
        product.save()
```

The `text2` and `text3` I'm sending null but creating in the database I'm not understanding why these are creating. Thanks

Comment: Should `request.POST['category_id ']` be `request.POST['category_id']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be inclined to use `if len(text2) > 0:` or just `if text2`.  You might be getting empty strings `""` in the POST data so your tests are always `True`.